# dot file not sourced when running a command via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables, remote

When I run my program interactively, it works fine:

```
ssh somehost
$ ~/some/path/somescript.py
```

When I run my program over ssh directly, it doesn't work. The variable `PYTHONPATH` is not set, because `.bashrc` is not sourced.

```
ssh somehost ~/some/path/somescript.py
```

If I run `ssh somehost 'source ~/.bashrc; ~/some/path/somescript.py'`, it works fine.

But the latter wouldn't work for some other folks, e.g. using tcsh and not having a `~/.bashrc` at all).

What is *the* command to run a thing via ssh on another host that works for all shells?

Comment: Answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login, basically, ssh doesn't source .bashrc, you need to source your .bashrc via .bash_profile or other options.

Comment: @EightBitTony: No, that's a different issue. bzdjamboo's question is about a non-interactive session.

Comment: Actually the last answer in the link I posted appears to be valuable, ssh does source .bashrc, but it doesn't execute due to the check for being interactive.  I appreciate however, that your answer covers all the bases.

Comment: @EightBitTony: On that question, the accepted answer is a good solution for the asker but the answers don't tell the full story. SSH itself doesn't source anything. If your login shell is bash invoked as `bash`, then *it* sources `.bash_profile` or `.profile` for an interactive login, and `.bashrc` for a non-interactive login. If your login shell is bash invoked as `sh` or ash or ksh, it sources `.profile` for an interactive login and nothing for a non-interactive login.

Answer (score 15):

There is no standard per-user file that is run for non-interactive logins. You need to either make the program self-contained, so that it's able to find its dependencies without relying on non-default environment variables, or else explicitly set the environment, typically with

```
ssh somehost '. ~/.profile; exec ~/some/path/somescript.py'
```

You shouldn't be setting environment variables in `.bashrc`: this file is meant for interactive shells, and is read in each instance of bash. Environment variables should be set in `.profile`, which is read when you log in. Apart from the very small number of people who don't use a Bourne-style shell as their login shell, `.profile` does work for everyone, whether they use bash or zsh or csh or fish interactively. See also 
[Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile),
[Which setup files should be used for setting up environment variables with bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-setup-files-should-be-used-for-setting-up-environment-variables-with-bash).

That being said, there is a way to source a script every time you log in over ssh with a particular key. See [Is there a way to push shell config information when SSHing to a host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14919/is-there-a-way-to-push-shell-config-information-when-sshing-to-a-host/14948#14948), [sh startup files over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/sh-startup-files-over-ssh/4953#4953).

Comment: Now how do  I mark it "answered"? :-)

Comment: Along the left side of this answer section there should be up and down vote arrows and a vote counter. Just below that there should be the outline of a checkbox. You can click that to activate the answer accept function.

Comment: Thankl you all again, but apparently your answers didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Here is a bit newer formulation of the problem and my current understanding of the root of it.

Comment: Seems that I cannot add more than 60 or so chars here so I've got to ask my question separately again. Sorry ab. that. Again, this one is not solved, and digging much more for a couple of days didn't help.

Comment: @bzdjamboo You can't put newlines in comments, maybe that's what was bothering you. If you think your question was imprecise (i.e. my answer solves a subcase but not your subcase), edit it. If you think you asked the wrong question (i.e. my answer solves what you asked but not what you meant to ask), ask a new question.

Comment: I re-posted my problem at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15324/none-of-the-dot-files-is-sourced-when-running-bash-via-ssh-part-ii. Thanks all!

Comment: Works good! It helps me finish task: start local script (it contains environmental variables). `ssh ruser@192.168.1.130 -i "sshkey" '. ~/.profile; source /etc/profile.d/MyVariables.sh; ${BaseDir}/myscript.sh'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but for me the solution was different. My user was not configured to use bash as shell, it used zsh as shell instead, therefore the bash dot files were not run at login. Open /etc/passwd with a text editor and look for your username and what shell it uses:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh
```

This is how my user entry looks. Notice it says /bin/zsh instead of /bin/bash. For zsh, the correct dot file is ~/.zprofile. Its contents will be run every time you login using ssh.