# Use Environment Variables of User in Target Server during SSH

Tags: environment-variables

I am trying to write a script in **server1** which will be executed using **user1** to execute some commands in **server2** with **user2**

So in **server1** if I try to execute the below command using **user1**, I am not able to see the environment variables of **user2** (which is defined in */home/user2/.profile*)

user1> `ssh user2@server2 "env"`

Due to this I am not able to execute the **user2** specific commands from server1 using ssh.

Note : proper ssh is configured between server1/user1 and server2/user2, and I can view the processes running in server2 from server1 if I give

user1> `ssh user2@server2 "ps -ef|grep user2"`

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

```
user1> ssh user2@server2 '$env'
```

### Long answer

You're missing a `$` in your first example of running an ssh command...if you really did type `ssh user2@server2 "env"` then the `"env"` would stay a literal string and not expand into any environment variables.

If you want **user2** to execute a command using **user2**'s environment variables, you need to pass a string that, when run, will expand into those variables. For example:

```
user1> ssh user2@server2 'echo $PATH'
```

Would echo **user2**'s `PATH` to the terminal.

However, you also need to know that when you run a command via ssh, `~/.profile` is **not** run beforehand (see discussion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15212/238000)). So, if you want access to environment variables defined in `~/.profile`, run this:

```
user1> ssh user2@server2 'source ~/.profile; $env'
```

**WARNING**: If you use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`), then the shell run by **user1** will expand any environment variables inside the double quotes to **user1**'s environment variables *before* the command ever gets sent across ssh to **user2**.