# None of the dot-files is sourced when running bash via ssh, part II

Tags: bash, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dot file not sourced when running a command via ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/dot-file-not-sourced-when-running-a-command-via-ssh)

This is a continuation of prev. my question [dot file not sourced when running a command via ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/dot-file-not-sourced-when-running-a-command-via-ssh) (I could not add enough information at the orig. post as it only allows 600 characters. Sorry if I did it wrong).

---

In a nut shell:
 if I have **bash** as the default shell on host1 and on host2, and

if I run from host1 the following:

> ssh host2 ~/some/path/somescript.py 
>   it doesn't work.

This is because *none* of the .-files are sourced on the remote host so my PYTHONPATH is not set and =the command fails.

---

This brings us to a shorter version of the problem:

**There is no . file that is sourced when I run bash on a remote host (i.e. non-interactively).**

To prove this, I created on the remote host the following files:

- .bash_login
- .bash_profile
- .bashrc
- .profile

and added as a 1st line an echo command to each of them, namely:

- to .bash_login : echo "hi from .bash_login"
- to .bash_profile : echo "hi from .bash_profile"
- to .bashrc : echo "hi from .bashrc"
- to .profile : echo "hi from .profile"

However if I run say

> ssh name@host2 "ls ~/foo"
>   I only see an output of "ls" but no echo output.

And why indeed it would echo? The man actually says:

> When bash is started non-interactively, to  run  a  shell  script,  for  example, it looks > for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and 
>   uses the expanded value as the  name  of  a  file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if > the following command were executed:
>              if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
>   but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search f

In other words, seems that *according to the manual* when bash is started non-interactively there is NO .-file that it runs by default.

One has to set it in an env. var-le "BASH_ENV" if she wants to source a file.

But then this seems to be an impossible thing to accomplish as... where one can set BASH_ENV or anything else as there is no file that is sourced?!?!?!?

This seems crazy. Am I the only man on Earth who needs to run bash non-interactively on a remote machine via ssh?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? I see your problem, and I've already covered it fairly extensively in my [answer to your previous question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/15212#15212) and in some [previous](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14919/is-there-a-way-to-push-shell-config-information-when-sshing-to-a-host/14948#14948) [posts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/sh-startup-files-over-ssh/4953#4953) I'd cited. But what are you asking now?

Comment: .. the character limit on questions is massively longer than anything you have entered. You must have tried to type a comment, which have a 600char limit. You need to go to your original question and **edit** the question to include the additional information, then ask for this one to to be delete.

Comment: I went with "duplicate" since it's supposed to be an edit. Once you've [edited the original post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/15207/edit) we can just delete this version

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to source one of those files and then run your .py script within the same ssh call by doing something like `ssh user@host ". ./.dot-command && python_script.py`

Comment: Thanks, but this solution doesn't work for me (I explained it in the prev. post and forgot to add here). The reason is: this needs to be run for all shells (e.g. including tsch / sch) and all users.

Comment: Also important; assume that there are hundreds of such commands somewhere in the codebase; to use your solution I'll have to change the code everywhere. This is doable but seems to be so ugly.

Comment: The question stands; how to make bash source some file automatically when running a non-interactive session. There must be a way, right?

Comment: @bzdjamboo The way is to explicitly tell the shell to source a file, i.e. `ssh hostname '. /path/to/script; actual-command-to-run'`. If users need to be targets of your automatic runs, they must have a compatible shell.