# Why is rsync not found?

Tags: rsync, path

```
rsync -avP /home/user/.profile hpux3:/home/user/.profile
bash: rsync: command not found
```

If I did ssh to hpux3 machine

```
rsync  
version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2014 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
output truncated
```

I have set `PATH` in `$HOME/.profile` and `$HOME/.bashrc`. Should I set it in the `/etc/profile` file?

Comment: The `rsync` command must be present on your local machine.

Comment: Of course is present in both machines

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your `.profile` is only read when you log in interactively. When rsync connects to another machine to execute a command, `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` are not read.

If your login shell is bash, then `~/.bashrc` may be read (this is a quirk of bash — `~/.bashrc` is read by non-login interactive shells, and in some circumstances by login non-interactive shells). This doesn't apply to all versions of bash though.

The easiest way to make rsync work is probably to pass the `--rsync-path` option, e.g.

```
rsync --rsync-path=/home/elbarna/bin/rsync -avP /home/user/.profile hpux3:/home/user/.profile
```

If you log in over SSH with key-based authentication, you can set the `PATH` environment variable via your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. See [sh startup files over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/sh-startup-files-over-ssh/4953#4953) for explanations of how to arrange to load `.profile` when logging in over SSH with a key.

Comment: Note: `--rsync-path` is used to set the path of `rsync` on the **remote** computer. (at first sight I was wondering how was it possible to specify the path to `rsync` while lauching `rsync` on the same machine)

Comment: @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' Any idea why I have to do this? Bash is not  my default shell. Ksh is my default shell. I login with ksh then switch to bash.

Comment: @cokedude If rsync is installed on your account rather than at the system level, you have to do some configuration on your account to be able to use it. It's not enough to put the `rsync` binary somewhere: you also need to arrange for it to be found.

Answer (score 26):

This error can also occur when trying to sync files and directories from remote machine to local system, if the rsync is not installed on the remote side.

```
rsync -zarvh oem@172.20.0.12:/var/www/html/release /var/www/html/release
bash: rsync: command not found
```

Installing rsync on remote side will solve this case

Comment: Note that the issue here is not that the utility isn't installed on the remote system, but that it's installed in a location on the remote system which is not in the default `$PATH`.