# Gitbash (MINGW64) - bash: rsync: command not found

Tags: bash

I want to copy a file from a local machine to a remote machin. Im using gitbash (MINGW64) to run the following command but I get error `bash: rsync: command not found`

```
rsync -avz  c/local/directory/image.png user@10.10.0.1:/remote/directory/
```

How do I install resync for gitbash?

I've read the following post ([Why is rsync not found?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198756/why-is-rsync-not-found)) which mentions adding the path to resync as quick solution but what is the path for resync on windows?

```
rsync --rsync-path=/home/elbarna/bin/rsync -avz  c/local/directory/image.png user@10.10.0.1:/remote/directory/
```

Comment: When you said "resync", did you mean "rsync"?

Answer (score 3):

Manage to fix by downloading the latest rsync file directly from http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/ extracting it. Then copy rsync at `./usr/bin/rsync.exe` and paste it into the `/usr/bin` folder of the Git installation.
On my machine, that is `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/`