# Is it possible to install rsync without sudo?

Tags: rsync

I have access to a webserver (a generic cheap PHP host) which has a bunch of smaller files that I want to take backups of. I can access with FTP but this is very slow. I can copy the files with `scp`, but one has to manually compress first, since the `-C` [argument compresses each file, not all files, before sending](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218668/what-does-the-c-flag-exactly-do-in-scp). Ideally, I would just like to use `rsync` like normal. The server admin told me they would not install it. Is it possible to install this without access to `apt` or `sudo` as a portable binary?

I found the rsync binary for Ubuntu at https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/binaries/ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/ (via https://rsync.samba.org/download.html). After setting `chmod +x`, I get this error:

```
[user@server]$ ./rsync
./rsync: error while loading shared libraries: libxxhash.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a clever way to acquire the missing library files all at once?

The server appears to be running Red Hat:

```
[user@server]$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.49.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@buildfarm03.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Mar 4 05:39:46 EST 2021
```

I don't see a precompiled version of `rsync` for this distro. What to do here? I cannot compile things on the server due to lacking libraries (very likely).

**Dependencies**

berndbausch asks in comments about the result of `ldd rsync`, which should show the required libraries:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007ffe589a3000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f6a681a5000) 
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6a67f8f000) 
libpopt.so.0 => /lib64/libpopt.so.0 (0x00007f6a67d85000) 
liblz4.so.1 => /lib64/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f6a67b76000) 
libzstd.so.1 => /lib64/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f6a6789d000) 
libxxhash.so.0 => not found 
libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found 
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6a674cf000) 
libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f6a672ca000) 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6a683ae000)
```

So it appears there are only 2 missing ones.

**`Rsync` from local machine to sercer**

Someone suggested in a now deleted comment to try rsync from local via ssh to server instead of the other way around. This doesn't work. It will give [an error like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611294/175112):

```
rsync -zarvh oem@172.20.0.12:/var/www/html/release /var/www/html/release
bash: rsync: command not found
```

Comment: See which libraries it wants/needs with `ldd ./rsync`. You get better compression efficiency by compressing the 1 big file (the archive) than by compressing any number of small files individually.

Comment: Added `ldd` output to question text. Good idea.

Comment: Since the host appears to be a Red Hat clone, have you tried using the compatible [rsync binary](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/binaries/centos-7.8-x86_64/) instead of the Ubuntu one to see if it works better?

Answer (score 0):

Unpack rsync and the required missing libraries to e.g. `$HOME/rsync`

Run `rsync` this way:

```
cd $HOME/rsync
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./rsync
# or
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/rsync
$HOME/rsync/rsync
```

> Where does one find these missing libraries for download?

1. Run `rsync`, you'll see missing libraries.
2. For each of them run the following: `dnf whatprovides '*/library.so'`
3. Download the required RPMs from any mirror
4. Use e.g. `rpm2cpio` and then `cpio -idv -F file.cpio` to extract the RPMs.

---

Lastly you can compile rsync on another PC statically and copy the resulting file back to your server.

Comment: Where does one find these missing libraries for download?