# Sourcing BASH_ENV for non-interactive SSH commands

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm hoping to get the `$BASH_ENV` var to source for non-interactive ssh commands.

I do see my BASH_ENV:

```
ssh server.example.com env | grep BASH
BASH_ENV=/tmp/set_bash_env_profile
```

If I do simple ssh login, and `env | wc -l` I get 85, thanks to `$BASH_ENV` env var, but if:

```
ssh server.example.com env | wc -l
17
```

I get just 17...

I tried `ForceCommand` in the sshd_config as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/353442/set-environment-variables-for-non-interactive-ssh) but in my case, the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is not being set.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you're setting `BASH_ENV` in your `.bashrc`. Bash loads `.bashrc` when it's interactive and not a login shell, *or* when it's a login shell that's invoked by rshd or (in many distributions, but it's a compile-time option) sshd. That's too late for *this* instance of bash. Put the commands directly in `~/.bashrc`.

```
# .bashrc
if [[ $- = *i* ]]; then
  # Commands for interactive use: prompt, aliases, key bindings, etc.
  # Don't set environment variables here, that goes in .profile.
else
  # Commands executed only on remote logins.
  # You can set environment variables here. Do not output anything.
fi
```

If you only need to set environment variables, you can use `~/.pam_environment` instead, which is used for any kind of login. See [What's the best distro/shell-agnostic way to set environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables)

For other ways to execute commands when logging in non-interactively over SSH, see [sh startup files over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/sh-startup-files-over-ssh/4945)

Comment: I'm setting `BASH_ENV` in `/etc/environment`, as I want the effects of `$BASH_ENV` to affect EVERY user. (and I can't simply put all vars in `/etc/environment` as `$BASH_ENV` stipulates on `$LOGNAME` as it sets up the variables)